# ASP.Net to build a web API that supports multi-threading

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I developed a web api using ASP.Net's webforms (empty page, codefile contains the code and returns the response using an exception that stops the application & uses response.write to display the results/error), but already facing a few problems that I'm not sure how to resolve. This is my first time using ASP.Net for anything, I went with it simply because I could develop the back-end in C#, which sped up production by a lot.

The problem is, whenever someone tries to use more than 8 simultaneous connections on the ASP.Net page, the connection from the client timeouts everything above the 8 connections.

I've contacted my hosting company to ask whether or not there is a limitation like that, but was told that there was none. I also looked into it myself, and found something similar, but in the end, nothing that I tried solved my issue.

I have tried...

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Services.DefaultServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

along with...

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
</connectionManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default connection limit (the latter of your configs) applies client side and limits the number of concurrent outbound connections.

Instead then of applying the config at the server side, apply it at the client side.